# Informatica is not using index defined in oracle for update

Tags: oracle, informatica-powercenter

I have 60 million data in my Orcale table.

I am loading data through informatica.

Keys are defined in informatica level and no keys in DB but i have an index in DB oracle. when i run the updates, Informatica is not using Unique index i declared in DB instead it is going for full table scan.

Is there any way to make this informatica update query use the index for updates??

### EDIT

Query in use is

```
UPDATE /*+index (a STG_MSF623_IDX)*/ STG_MSF623 a
  SET WO_TASK_DESC = :TU.WO_TASK_DESC,
      WORK_GROUP = :TU.WORK_GROUP,
      CREW = :TU.CREW
  WHERE DSTRCT_CODE = :TU.DSTRCT_CODE AND
        WORK_ORDER = :TU.WORK_ORDER AND
        WO_TASK_NO = :TU.WO_TASK_NO
```

Comment: What are you updating? What is the final query? Updates may have to do full scan if you are going to  unindexed columns. Also, when you make the same update directly in oracle, is the explain plan any different?

Comment: Explain Plan cost for direct update in Oracle is 3. but for the same update through informatica is taking a cost of 65000. and to update i am using the index columns in where clause of target override.

Comment: Can you provide the query its producing ?

Comment: UPDATE /*+index (a STG_MSF623_IDX)*/ STG_MSF623 a SET WO_TASK_DESC = :TU.WO_TASK_DESC, WORK_GROUP = :TU.WORK_GROUP, CREW = :TU.CREW WHERE DSTRCT_CODE = :TU.DSTRCT_CODE AND WORK_ORDER = :TU.WORK_ORDER AND WO_TASK_NO = :TU.WO_TASK_NO

Comment: And how much data is there on the map? how much records should be updated?

Comment: Data is 6o million and i am just giving a try with one row upadate,its taking 30 minutes and going for full table scan

Comment: Have you collected statistics on this table? `BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('table owner', 'table name'); END;`

Comment: Got the solution the target table datatype is nvarchar so index on the column is not been used.

Answer (score 0):

Use an INDEX hint on your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE /*+ INDEX(yt THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_INDEX) */
  YOURTABLE yt
  SET yt.COL1 = 'something',
      yt.COL2 = 'something else'
  WHERE yt.INDEXED_COLUMN = 'whatever'
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I have tried that option also but of no use. If i declare primary keys at DB level and use target override with INDEX hint its taking that but also its going for index full but not index unique scan